# jQuery pagination previous next buttons

Tags: jquery, html, pagination, navigation

I have the following problem: I would like to add a previous and next button to my pagination. I created a problem fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b8gmqx9p/7/

As you can see, I got the pagination / navigation bar both on top and bottom of my content. Since I have lots of elements within my content, I would like to have a previous and next button to establish easier navigation.

Let's also assume I got 20 pages in my navigation and I would like to only display five pages, like that: 'previous | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | next' and if you click on page 4, you'll get 'previous | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | next'. Unfortunately I don't know how to establish that.

So I would really appreciate your input on both issues. Thanks so much in advance!

This is the jQuery code:

```
( function($) {

                $.fn.customPaginate = function(options) {
                    var paginationContainer = this;
                    var itemsToPaginate;

                    var defaults = {

                        itemsPerPage : 3

                    };

                    var settings = {};

                    $.extend(settings, defaults, options);

                    var itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;

                    itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
                    var numberOfPaginationLinks = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / itemsPerPage));


                    $("<ul></ul>").prependTo(paginationContainer);

                    for(var pagerEle=0; pagerEle<paginationContainer.length; pagerEle++){                            
                        for (var index = 0; index < numberOfPaginationLinks; index++) {                            
                            paginationContainer.eq(pagerEle).find("ul").append("<li>" + (index + 1) + "</li>");
                            if(index == 0){
                                paginationContainer.eq(pagerEle).find("ul li").eq(0).addClass('pagination_active');
                            }
                        }
                    }



                    itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + (itemsPerPage - 1) + ")").hide();

                    paginationContainer.find("ul li").on('click', function(e) {

                        var linkNumber = $(this).text();

                        var itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(":lt(" + ((linkNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage) + ")");
                        $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + ((linkNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1) + ")"));
                        itemsToHide.hide();

                        var itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
                        itemsToShow.show("300");

                        $(this).addClass('pagination_active').siblings().removeClass('pagination_active');
                        pagerCurIndex = $(this).index();

                        for(var pagerEle=0; pagerEle<paginationContainer.length; pagerEle++){                            
                            paginationContainer.eq(pagerEle).find("ul li").eq(pagerCurIndex).addClass('pagination_active').siblings().removeClass('pagination_active');
                        }


                    });

                }
            }(jQuery));

        (function($) {

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $(".pagination").customPaginate({

                    itemsToPaginate : ".pagination_show"

                });

            });

        })(jQuery)
```

Comment: have u got the solution for this. ? if yes pls share the same 
Thanks